# PUTTY access Denied

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to login using putty SSH it showing error "Access Denied Using Keyboard-interactive authentication.", I am trying with correct id and password.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution found.

I'd try:

1- SSH Config Reset http://YOURIPADDRESS:2086/scripts2/doautofixer?autofix=safesshrestart

2- Host Access Control add sshd ip allow

3- Manage root’s SSH Keys key creat and putty connect

4- Cpanel any domain login -> create ssh key > putty login `su root`

5- WHM Service Manager sshd enabled

6- Other root username login test

But not login.

**SOLUTION:**

any domain ssh connect via key -> **vim /etc/passwd** or **vi /etc/passwd**

*/etc/passwd (preview):*

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash^M
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin^M
...
```

**PROBLEM = ^M**

Contact system administration clear ^M char **solved**.

Note: Because I have already edited the passwd file in the "windows" environment. Do not edit windows editor.

**For edit:** Putty another login and `su root` -> `vim /etc/passwd` -> clear all ^M -> For Save `:wq`, For Not save quit `:q!`

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

If that does not work try using the command line:

> putty.exe -l [LOGIN] -pw [PASSWORD] [HOST]

**---END EDIT---**

Try unchecking the encircled checkbox.

[image: Putty Configuration]

Comment: it's not showing "Keyboard-interactive authentication." anymore but still showing Access Denied error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are logging in as a user that is blocked (this error can happen if trying to login as root).

If you need to be a blocked user, try logging in as another user then after you are successfully logged in,

Run Command :

```
su amit
```

or

```
su root
```

as the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing `/etc/passwd` utilizing vim to remove the `^M` you can just install dos2unix to fix that issue.

```
sudo apt install dos2unix -y
sudo dos2unix /etc/passwd
```

The `^M` typically happens when someone edits the Linux file in a Windows text editor and then saves that file back to a Linux system. The Linux system picks up on the end of line character placed by Windows and see's it as a `^M`